# Bricking up a bathroom window

Tags: bathroom, windows

In my bathroom there are two windows - one of them shown on the picture:

[image: bathroom window]

The window does not open and severely limits my options of re-decorating the bathroom. Ideally, I would like to brick it up.

Now, how difficult it would be to do it?

Can this be done from inside the bathroom only? (without setting up a scaffolding). I am concerned with the cost of the scaffolding. I am also not sure, how to do it, as there is a sloped roof underneath the window.

If access from outside is needed to do the job, can it be done in stages - e.g. put in some stub, refit the bathroom and only later brick up from outside?

Any suggestions welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the inside window frame, maybe with a tape measure so we can see the depth(inside wall to window)?  I am worried the changing that window and bricking it up will leave you with a outside wall looking like it has a big non matching patch on it, unless you could make the patch look like a big sun flower(or something).

Comment: Is that UK? You'd need planning permission.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple questions here.  The fact that you do tells me that this is something you should leave for professionals.

There is no need for scaffolding. Scaffolding will not reach the window. A professional brick mason or skilled handyman will make a platform so they can work safely on the roof without damaging it.

We don't know if the window can be removed from the inside, or if it requires brick to be removed from the outside.  This is another reason a professional should be employed.

The job can be done in stages. However those stages should be:  Window removal,  closing the opening with brick, ( or another material), framing inside, insulation, closing the interior wall, finishing with your chosen surface.

Doing everything else and then bricking up the outside would not be wise.

If you plan to do the interior work your self, OR not, you should consult a few contractors and get proposals.

Comment: Can I leave the window as is and simply block from inside, then put tiles on the wall?

Comment: Being in a bath, I personally would not recommend that.  Condensation growing on the inside of the window and causing problems would be my concern.  However in your area there may be contractors that know what products and methods to use that have proven  to work well.  I would consult them.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask an contractor for an custom made openable window. Then you would have fresh air and light.

Alternatively you could fit drywall on the inside and leave the window as it is. Therefor you would have no hassle with the brickwork.

Comment: Nice outside-the-box thinking....